# Block specific links in redirected page in c#

Tags: c#, .net, url, browser, webbrowser-control

I am creating an test where I provide certain help links to the candidate along with the question. Now I the user must be able to browse through the redirected site but cannot go to any external site via that.
Following are my queries,

1. For I am opening the new site in separate window, how do I access its
   URL or document itself ?
2. How to I block specific links code wise ?

I am a newbie here, so got very little idea on this code wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) For I am opening the new site in separate window, how do I access
    its URL or document itself?

> [WebBrowser.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Property - Gets or sets the URL of the current document.
>
> [WebBrowser.Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Property - Use this property when you want to access the contents of a Web page displayed in the WebBrowser control through the HTML document object model (DOM)

2) How to I block specific links code wise?

> You can handle the [Navigating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event to cancel navigation if certain conditions have not been met, for example, when the user has not completely filled out a form. To cancel navigation, set the Cancel property of the WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs object passed to the event handler to true.

Comment: That worked, but is there any alternate other than webbrowser control to do this, like iframes ?

Comment: webbrowser control is well known; alternatives are GeckoFX, OpenWebKitSharp, Awesomium; not sure what do you mean by iframes

Comment: since a web browser control restricts its users for only IE, I am thinking of other options as well. It is a web application that I am developing, so what would be a better choice to webbrowser control ?

Comment: Check awesomium, API is available for C++ and .NET on Windows, Mac OSX, and Linux; It has a free licence for For Teams with < $100K Revenue, For Non-Commercial Purposes, For Educational Purposes, Community Support; Otherwise licence cost 2900$